# ¿Cómo busco con Grep las palabras que empiezan por "i"?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Estoy aprendiendo los usos de grep y me gustaría usarlo para buscar diferentes patrones en un archivo de texto. Tengo unos problemas a la hora de buscar los patrones exactos y me gustaría saber qué estoy haciendo mal.

Al buscar en mi archivo de texto todas las palabras que empiecen por la letra i

```
grep '^i.' archivo.txt
```

me devuelve el nombre de las filas que comienzan por i en lugar de las palabras que comienzan por "i".

Comment: aprendiz, sería bueno que indicaras si las soluciones te han funcionado y aceptaras las que lo hicieron. Si no, las preguntas quedarán en limbo

Answer (score 1):

El carácter `^` indica "inicio de línea". Por tanto, cuando dices `^i.` le estás diciendo "busca todo aquellas líneas que empiecen por 'i' y tengan luego al menos un carácter más":

```
$ cat fichero
hola que tal i1 i
i muy bien
bla
$ grep '^i.' fichero
i muy bien
```

Si lo que quieres es buscar todas las palabras que empiecen por "i" y tengan al menos un carácter después, puedes utilizar:

```
\bi.
```

`\b` significa "límite de palabra", por lo que sirve tanto para inicio de línea como para inicio de palabra.

```
$ grep '\bi.' fichero
hola que tal i1 i
i muy bien
```

Si solamente quieres ver las coincidencias, usa `-o` (the "only"):

```
$ grep -o '\bi.' fichero
i1
i
```

Para coger la palabra completa, usa lo indicado por Emerson:

```
grep -o '\bi\w*' fichero
```

Comment: Gracias! ¿Hay alguna forma con -o (o con otra opción) de poder ver las palabras completas? Solamente me devuelve la primera sílaba.

Comment: @aprendiz claro, te devuelve exactamente lo que encaja con `i.`. Edita tu pregunta con un ejemplo para ver claramente qué quieres, si solo la palabra o la línea entera.

Answer (score 1):

Para ver la palabra completa debes hacer una expresión que diga: "separador de palabras, seguido de una `i`, seguido de 0 o más caracteres seguido del próximo separador de palabras".

Si tu archivo fuera

```
hola que tal ignacio
estuve viendo que el intendente
no hizo su trabajo
infiero que debes hacerle una llamada
al anexo i203
```

La expresión

```
grep '\bi\w*\b' fichero
```

Mostraría

> hola que tal **ignacio**
>
> estuve viendo que el **intendente**
>
> **infiero** que debes hacerle una llamada
>
> al anexo **i203**

Otra manera de hacerlo sería decirle:

"separador de palabras, seguido de una `i`, seguido de 0 o más caracteres **que no sean** un separador de palabras".

Pero por defecto `grep` no soporta esa negación. Para habilitarlo, puedes pasarle la opción `-P` para que use la sintaxis de Perl:

```
grep -P '\bi[^\b]*?\b' fichero
```

Ojo, que caracteres como puntos, guiones, comas o underscore también son separadores de palabras, así que `i-203` sólo encontraría `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Esta podría considerarse como otra opción:

```
grep -Eio "[^(a-zA-Z)]i\w+" archivo.txt
```

Explico a continuación el mismo:

- parámetros utilizados:

  - E: indica al comando grep que busque utilizando la expresión regular dada;
  - i: indica al comando grep que no tome en cuenta las mayúsculas, es decir, tus resultados deben coincidir tanto si lo que buscas está en minúscula o en mayúscula;
  - o: incida al comando grep que te muestre las coincidencias completas, sin "texto" a su alrededor
- acerca de la expresión regular utilizada:

  - ciertamente *(como han mencionado)* `^` se utiliza para indicar inicio de línea, pero en combinación con los corchetes cuadrados `[...]` indica **negación**, de forma tal que en `[^(a-zA-Z)]` estoy indicando que no inicie con ninguna otra letra más que con "i" *(mayúscula o minúscula, utilizando el parámetro -i presentado arriba)*;
  - i: tu condición, la letra con la que estás buscando inicie la(s) palabra(s);
  - \w+: le siga cualquier juego de letras o números para terminar de conformar la palabra;

Comment: No, `[^(a-zA-Z)]i\w+` no quiere decir lo que dices. Lo que hace esta expresión es buscar una "i" seguida de algún carácter alfanumérico, pero que siga a cualquier carácter que no sea `(`, `a-z`, `A-Z` ni `)`. Por tanto, esto devolverá cosas como "_ib", "?ic" u " iata", pero no "(ib". Puedes probarlo con `echo "(ib _ib ?ic iata" | grep -Eio "[^(a-zA-Z)]i\w+"`.

Comment: Estás pues complicando la regex mucho más de lo necesario. Si lo que quieres es buscar aquello que empieza por "i", díselo --> `grep '\bi.'`, que es lo que propongo en mi solución.

Comment: entiendo tu punto @fedorqui, tu comando podría entonces quedar así `grep -io '\bi\w*'`, ¿a que sí?, tomando en consideración que se están buscando **palabras completas**, entendiéndose éstas como un conjunto de letras seguidas sin espacios ni caracteres especiales, correcto?

Comment: bueno, quedó pendiente que el OP (autor de la pregunta) ofreciera algún dato más de lo que busca, pero sí, efectivamente lo que comentas sería una solución correcta (más que la que propuse, de hecho, por lo que con tu permiso voy a editar mi respuesta).

Comment: claro, súper mi aporte sea considerado, saludos!